# Show/Hide li elements from ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to hide some particular li elements from an ul based on a form logic as follow: if some textboxes are in blank hide particular li elements from the menu (ul). The thing is that they are not using id nor classes on li. Please kindly see my fiddle code: `https://jsfiddle.net/u0dx0qpo/

This is the whole logic, if mentioned inputs are blank show only "Download & Print Applications" and "FAQS" else show full menu.

This is the function I was trying to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
        if ($("#firstname").val() == "" || $("#lastname").val() == "" || $("#socialsecuritynumber").val() == "" || $("#emailaddress1").val() == ""){
            // $('li').not('[title="Download &amp; Print Applications"]').hide();
        }
});
```

Or better yet, I dont know if is possible to hide some particular li based on other attribute such as title, something like: `$('att:xx').hide();` as I'm using another menu in the same page that I don't want to affect or modify from this code...

Comment: Is it fixed that Download and Print Applications and FAQ would be at 3 and 4th positions

Comment: It is not a good practice to check with the titles of li values, because if any point of time their values change you need to modify your conditions too,which would be tightly coupled

Comment: You can better add some classes to download and faqs and check using the classes

Comment: You should edit your question to 1) add jQuery to your JSFiddle build, 2) properly wrap your code in brackets and parentheses, and 3) add `id` attributes to your DOM elements (or at least explain why it's not possible to).

Comment: Sorry for my Ignorance but I don't see that solution, could you guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few things going on with your existing code that will prevent it from properly functioning:

1. Targeting `title="FAQS"` (plural), not `title="FAQ"` (singular)
2. Target HTML escaped `&`, not `&amp;`
3. Target against `a` elements, then hide the parent `li`

   ```
   if ($("#firstname").val() == "" ||
       $("#lastname").val() == "" ||
       $("#socialsecuritynumber").val() == "" ||
       $("#emailaddress1").val() == "") {
     $('a').not('[title="Download & Print Applications"],[title="FAQS"]').parent().hide();
   }
   ```

[Here's the corrected JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0dx0qpo/5/).

**Alternatively**, if you'd like to update the UI upon changes in the `input` elements, you'd want something like the following:

```
$("input").on('change', function() {
  if ($("#firstname").val() == "" ||
      $("#lastname").val() == "" ||
      $("#socialsecuritynumber").val() == "" ||
      $("#emailaddress1").val() == "") {
    $('a').not('[title="Download & Print Applications"],[title="FAQS"]').parent().hide();
  } else {
    $('li').show();
  }
});
```

The `else` conditions ensures that – upon evaluation – that all `li` elements that were previously hidden are redisplayed.

[Here's the corresponding JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0dx0qpo/7/).

**UPDATE**:

Per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066346/show-hide-li-elements-from-ul/40066510#comment67416827_40066510) regarding *explicitly* targeting DOM elements, given the [original JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0dx0qpo/), you can simply specify the the enclosing div `class` thusly:

```
$('.navbar-left a').not('...')
...
$('.navbar-left li').show();
```

Comment: Works well like this, however it is hiding other options from another menu existing in the same page. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can target more granularly by encapsulating this particular markup within a `div` element. The code I've provided is based only on the markup in your original JSFiddle. If this answer works well, as you've mentioned, please consider upvoting or [accepting it as correct](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Quick question @zeantsoi, how can you specify in that function that you want to apply that logic to that specific ul with the class named: xxx in order to avoid apply same logic in others menu in same page that I don't want?

Comment: @john I've added an explanation for more granular DOM targeting. If it helps, you may want to consider upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide or show a specific `<li>` with jQuery and you're not using id's or classes, you can use jQuery's nth child selector.

For example, you can hide the third one with

`$('.weblinks-depth-1 li:nth-child(3)').hide();`

https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jquery you can access elements with other attributes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
        if ($("#firstname").val() == "" || $("#lastname").val() == "" || $("#socialsecuritynumber").val() == "" || $("#emailaddress1").val() == ""){
          $('li').hide();
          $("li[data-sitemap-node='/knowledge-base/article/']").show();
          $("li[data-sitemap-node='/content/blank-page/']").show();      
        }
});
```

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0dx0qpo/6/)

Comment: I think I should hide one by one all li with this jquery function since I have another menu in the same page that I dont wanna touch, means I can not say $('li').hide() unless I specify somewhere the ul and class specifically to apply the hidden (ul class="weblinks-depth-1 nav navbar-nav")...

Comment: Hiding all elements before showing some is going to cause the DOM to flicker needlessly upon re-render.

Comment: yes.. hiding one by one makes more sense than hiding all and showing the required @John

Answer (score 0):

I updated some of the ids on the if statement to ensure the code would execute and chose to hide all the **li**s, then reveal the one with the desired link.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#username").val() == "" 
       || $("#lastname").val() == "" 
       || $("#socialsecuritynumber").val() == "" 
       || $("#emailaddress1").val() == ""){
        $('li').hide();
        $('li > a[title="Download & Print Applications"]').parent().show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first go and check if the inputs type "text" are empty by cycling through them like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function checkInputs(){
        var emptyInputs = false;
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(element){
            if( $(this).val() ) {
                $('li a').not('[title="Download & Print Applications"]').hide();
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    $('input[type="text"]').on( 'keydown',function(){
        checkInputs();
    });
});
```

hope it helps,
Leo.

Comment: for sure it helps too!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter: (put this in document ready OR another event handler)
You might need to modify the classes in the wrapper div that I used; not knowing your other menu...

```
  if ($("#username").val() == "" || $("#lastname").val() == "" || $("#socialsecuritynumber").val() == "" || $("#emailaddress1").val() == "") {
    $('.weblinks.navbar-left').find('li').filter(function() {
      return !$(this).find('[title*="Download & Print Applications"]').length && !$(this).find('[title*="FAQS"]').length;
    }).hide();
  }
```